# Axios POST request payload is not arriving at endpoint

Tags: typescript, express, axios

I've got 2 Express servers running. A gateway and an authentication service. I'm trying to make a request from my gateway to my authentication server, and there aren't any CORS problems that I can see. However, whatever payload I set in my body, it never arrives to my authentication service. But if I try the same request from something like Postman it works fine. This is my controller for the authentication service:
`authentication-service controller`

```
export const post = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
  const newUser = req.body;

  if (newUser.email === undefined || newUser.password === undefined) {
    log.debug(newUser);
    log.debug('Email and password were not defined');
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  } else {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  }
}
```

`gateway`

```
const data = new FormInfo();
  data.append('email', 'test');
  data.append('password', 'test');

  console.log(data);

  const registerRes = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: process.env.REGISTER_USER_URL,
    headers: {
      ...data.getHeaders(),
    },
    data,
  })
      .then((response: any) => response)
      .catch((error) => error.response);
```

I've been scratching my head for days trying to figure this one out, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

I've tried disabling CORS.

I've also tried enabling CORS in this manner:

```
const whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000'];

      const corsOptions = {
        credentials: true,
        origin: (origin: any, callback: any) => {
          if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true);
          } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
          }
        },
      };

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Currently CORS is set this way:

```
app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by using `qs` instead of `FormInfo`. If anyone knows why this might be please let me know so I can update the answer.